# PayPals Instant Payments Notifications for WinForms

Tags: winforms, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working on a WinForms application that has the ability to create and send invoices. In addition to creating invoices locally, the app uses PayPals Permissions API(and the invoicing API) to allow the application to (optionally)send invoices on the clients behalf.

My question is as follows, what is the best method of keeping track of the current status of invoices sent using PayPal? The application needs to know the status of each invoice so it can update its records locally.

I am aware of PayPals Instant Payments Notifications although I am unsure how this would fit together with a WinForms application(?).

My initial thought was to use the PayPal Invoicing API to query the required information on a as and when need-to-know basis. Additionally, a function that ran on a different thread could be run periodically to retrieve information in the background from the API, updating records locally.

Am I failing to acknowledge a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

IPN will not fit invoice payment in case of creating invoice using permission API as there's no parameter to set the IPN URL in the invoice API. Your idea of calling GetInvoiceDetails API to retrieve invoice status based on need-to-know sounds a good solution for me.